# Symfony 2 how to import LESS files from another bundle

Tags: symfony, less, assetic

LESS has the power to @import other LESS files. This question is intended to find a solution to import LESS files within LESS files from another Bundle in a Symfony project

I'm working on a Symfony2 project, using LESS and Assetic to watch changes. My LESS files are able to import other LESS files but only if they are in the same bundle.

If I try to import from another bundle Assetic watch stops with error "variable undefined" because the import fails.

I've tried all sorts of paths in the import:

In a LESS file in another bundle:

```
@import "../../../../MainBundle/Resources/public/less/colors.less";

@import "../../../../../../src/website/MainBundle/Resources/public/less/colors.less";

@import '/bundles/main/less/colors.less'

@import url('/bundles/main/less/colors.less');
```

I'm sure I've tried several correct paths, but they never work because the file is in another bundle and the Assetic watch / LESS compilation processes don't do this well between the bundles.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Is it also an option for you to use assetic to combine the less files instead of importing them ffrom within one another?

Comment: Quite unlikely.. I need the possibility of importing other LESS files to extend behaviours of others, while I'm developing.

Comment: Look at filter definition, it seems that there is no way to pass any custom paths (for search for inclusion) https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/filters/less.xml. This is the method to call: https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/blob/master/src/Assetic/Filter/LessFilter.php#L59

Comment: Also, take a look at this issue (it's very similar, but it's for SASS): https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/202

Comment: This is a known issue and it should be fixed soon. Take a look at: https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/79 and https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/pull/362

Comment: thanks guys anyone looking to solve the same problem may watch this issue https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/79

Answer (score 5):

I think that you must use the paths from web/bundles dir.

i'm importing files this way:

i have 2 less files:

- `src/Acme/FirstBundle/Resources/public/less/style1.less`
- `src/Acme/SecondBundle/Resources/public/less/style2.less`

I want to import style1.less into style2.less

style2.less:

```
@import "../../acmefirst/less/style1";
```

using: cssrewrite filer, lessphp

also remember to refer the LESS files using their actual, publicly-accessible path:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-css-stylesheets

Comment: Works for Stylus filter (styl files) too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete working example at least on Symfony 2.8. This example using Assetic and is supposed to work with embed file in your css.

Here the arborescence

```
/app
/src
---/Acme
------/MyBundle
---------/Ressources
------------/public
---------------/css
------/MyOtherBundle
---------/Ressources
------------/public
---------------/css
/web
---/bundles
------/acmemybundle
------/acmemyotherbundle
---/css
------/built
```

So in  let's say */src/Acme/MyBundle/Ressources/public/css/main.scss* is the file with all the declaration that I want to import in my other bundle (in my case I use sass but it's the same with less).

In */src/Acme/MyOtherBundle/Ressources/public/css/mycss.scss* I'll do :

```
@import "../../../../MyBundle/Resources/public/css/main";
```

This refer to the classic physical location of the file, so your IDE will find it.

**Now the interesting part. We want to compile, minify, and rename all the scss file into only one css file.** We can do this with Assetics.

In a twig file where you load your css (in my case /app/Ressources/views/css.html.twig).

```
    {% stylesheets
    filter='compass'
    filter='?uglifycss'
    filter='cssrewrite'
    output='css/built/myMinifiedAndCompiledSass.css'
    'bundles/mybundle/css/*.scss'
    'bundles/myotherbundle/css/*.scss'
   %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}">
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

==> Here you have to refer the file from the /web directory (so using 'bundles/acmemybundle..' syntax. You need to install the asset in symlink mode. (php app/console asset:install --symlink)

==> You can put whatever you want in output filemane and location since you stay in the web directory.

And finaly in your conf.yml

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass:    ~
        compass:
             load_paths:
                  - "/usr/bin/compass"
                  - "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Acme/MyBundle/Resources/public/css/"
        uglifycss:
            bin: %kernel.root_dir%/../node_modules/.bin/uglifycss
        uglifyjs2:
            bin: %kernel.root_dir%/../node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs
```

**The important part here is the load_paths** in compass.
In the basic set up you have compass :  ~ 
You need to change it for :

```
  compass:
                 load_paths:
                      - "/usr/bin/compass"
                      - "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Acme/MyBundle/Resources/public/css/"
```