# Akeneo: Customize the UI (Modify CSS Less variables)

Tags: symfony, less, assets, akeneo

I have to adapt the colors of the Akeneo GUI to match the default company colors.

I've found `UIBundle/Resources/public/css/variables.less` where I could change the colors.

But how can I override this bundle? I get only the default purple colors.
I have also tried to add my file to `MyEnrichBundle/Resources/config/bundles/assetic.yml`, but I don't know to load this config.

Is there a "faster" way to test the compiled Less files than `php app/console pim:install --env=prod` (this line takes about 5 minutes for our default installation).

Comment: Have you try to include your less file directly in the header of your html page ?

Comment: this answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/13862508/5169651

Comment: including a less file in a html page will be useless. it must be parsed by a less filter before...

Answer (score 1):

It's not as easy as it seems to use mixins from one bundle in another one.

You could have a look at this topic to have some clue to begin with : [Symfony 2 how to import LESS files from another bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027780/symfony-2-how-to-import-less-files-from-another-bundle)

Generating assets without running a whole install is easy as a breeze : `app/console pim:installer:assets`

Comment: another interesting topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880751/akeneo-customize-the-ui-modify-css-less-variables. It's for Saas, but can maybe be applied to less files

Comment: Thanks, especially for your `app/console pim:installer:assets` hint. Unfortunately I still cannot **overwrite** the compiled CSS files from the Akeneo `UIBundle`. The link from your Saas-comment doesn't work?!

Comment: It should : i just verified. The basic principle is to import your mixins using a relative path to the other bundle. Not very smart, but i don't another way.